# Managing traffic on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm actually using Cloud Build & Cloud Run in my project.

For the CI/CD, I use a **cloudbuild.yaml** file to define the steps I need to perform to deploy my new revision of Cloud Run.

After several issue on traffic management, I had to add to my Cloud Build file a step to specify that the traffic should be set to 100% to the latest built revision. That is weird but it is working so... be it

**cloudbuild.yaml step**

```
# Allocate 100% of the traffic to that new revision
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['run', 'services', 'update-traffic', '${_APP_NAME}', '--to-revisions=LATEST=100', '--platform', 'gke', '--cluster', 'xxxxxx', '--cluster-location', 'xxxxxxxxxxx', '--namespace', 'xxxxxxxx']
```

Unfortunately, even if the traffic is well set, it always keeps "alive" the old revision  .

[image]

What is strange is that it is not doing it when I'm doing it remotely using `gcloud` command.
Did you already have that issue in the past ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This seems Cloud Run for Anthos-specific. Could be a bug on Google side. Your revision is likely not kept alive. Are you checking `kubectl get pods` a few minutes after updating the traffic and the Pod is still there? Don't let that green checkmark fool you. It doesn't any effect.

Comment: Did you play with revision URLs previously? Can you share the Cloud Build step to deploy the cloud run revision? Can you share your gcloud sdk version?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I will double check that. Thanks

Comment: @AhmetB-Google: I verified using `kubectl get pods` and yes the old revision is still alive after 30 minutes.

Comment: Are you using `minScale` feature (either on the KService or Revision YAML object annotations) or did you happen to change the `scale-to-zero` setting in the Knative ConfigMap)? This shouldn't happen as revisions with 0 traffic are scaled down to zero.

Comment: I'm using `--min-instances 1 `, but when the second one is deploy, the min instance should be set to the new one since all the traffic is also redirected to it ?